# NullReferenceException trying to read connection string

Tags: c#, sql, nullreferenceexception, configurationmanager

I have two projects. One is web & the other is windows forms. Web project connects to database but the windows project throws an exception NullReferenceException reading the connection string.

I am using the same classes to connect both projects. Connection is established using LINQTOSQL.

Here is my Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="GPSystemConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=GPSystem;User ID=***;Password=***"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is how i am reading it.

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GPSystemConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

(Exception occurs on this line)..... (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Note: i am using same class to connect both projects.... one connects but the other fails.

Please any one help me with this!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to have the appropriate entry in the app.config (for WinForms) *and* web.config (for the Web project) - these configurations are read for the *executing assembly* and are *not shared*.

Comment: @user2864740: It is possible to share them. See my answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Your answer really just steals the configuration ;-)

Comment: @user2864740: Isn't it wonderful? ;) I use this a lot. I have an own ORM mapping that reads the config file from the `ExecutingAssembly`. This method is really useful.

Comment: if you want to use a file for both projects you need to include it in your apps and if web project can read config just do it for another like this `var configs = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddXmlFile(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "same.config"))
          .Build();` check this [Configuration Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Answer (score 12):

You need to have entry in app.config for connection string in your window application.

If you don't have `App.Config` file then add it.

and put entry like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="GPSystemConnectionString"  connectionString="..." />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In you .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GPSystemConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 8):

I always struggle with this issue of null reference with the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString` when I have the data access layer in a different project/library than the executable. I often use the following to help debug the location of the configuration file at runtime:

```
var configfile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var path = configfile.FilePath;
```

Comment: This is a great tip to find out the root cause. I had the same problem when testing the LinqToSql code in the unit test project. In the end, I have to add the connection string in the app.config of the unit test project.

Comment: @fradsham - Great tip!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to [get the configuration section from another assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) use this:

```
Assembly assembly = ...; /* get the assembly to read config from */

System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(assembly.Location);

string CS = configuration.ConnectionStrings["GPSystemConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Can this be used to access the `web.config` from the WinForms application (as opposed to the `app.config` of another application)? I've never used this before.

Comment: @user2864740: The OP says that it shares classes, so I guess it also shares a common assembly. In that case this is a decent solution. It is also possible to read the web.config but you need the `WebConfigurationManager`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was due to ConnectionString in my 64bit Machine.Config

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config`

Rather than the standard 32-bit

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config`

To correct remove the Prefer 32-bit setting on the Build tab of Project Properties
[image: Build tab of Project]