# Checking in C# whether MySQL database exists

Tags: c#, mysql, console-application, database-schema, toplevel-statement

I'm writing a simple console application in C# using top-level statements, and I want to check at the beginning whethere there exists a database. Here's my code:

```csharp
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    if (CheckDatabaseExistence(connection)) Console.WriteLine("Database Exists.");
}

bool CheckDatabaseExistence(MySqlConnection connection)
{
    MySqlCommand myCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA" +
        "WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'database_name';";
    return Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;
}
```

After executing this code, I get the following error message:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE 'sql_store'' at line 1'

The SQL query syntax for checking database existence is from [MySQL Documentation, Section 24.3.22](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-schemata-table.html)

```mysql
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database`
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
  [WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'wild']
```

I've tried replacing `LIKE` with `=`, but I get the same error.

Comment: Concatenating strings is prone to this kind of errors. You missed a space between the two strings

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you :)

Comment: However I doubt that this code will work even after fixing the typo. SCHEMA_NAME is not an integer.

Comment: What type is it exactly? I worked around that with this code `return myCommand.ExecuteScalar() != null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a database exists in MySQL using a `Console App`, try the following:

**Create a `Console App`**

**VS 2022**:

- Open VS 2022
- Click [image]
- Click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- For filter, choose: [image]
- Select **Console App**
- Click **Next**
- Enter desired project name (ex: DatabaseMySqlTest) and select desired location.
- Click **Next**
- For Framework, select **.NET 6.0 (Long-term support)**
- Click **Create**

**Open Solution Explorer**:

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Install/Download NuGet package**: `MySql.Data`

- In Solution Explorer, expand <project name>
- Right-click <project name> and select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse** tab
- In the search box, type: **MySql.Data**
- Scroll to the top, and select **MySql.Data**
- Select desired version (ex: 8.0.31), and click **Install**
- If prompted *Visual Studio is about to make changes to this solution. Click OK to proceed with the changes listed below...*, click **OK**
- If a *License Acceptance* prompt appears, click the appropriate button.

---

**Option 1** (Application Configuration File)

**Add an `Application Configuration File` to your project** (name: App.config)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add New Item...**
- Select **Application Configuration File** (name: App.config)
- Click **Add**

**App.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MySqlConnectionAdmin" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=information_schema;Uid=test;Pwd=mySuperSecretPassword;" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Add a class** (name: HelperMySql.cs)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class...** (name: HelperMySql.cs)

**HelperMySql.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DatabaseMySqlTest
{
    public class HelperMySql
    {
        public static bool CheckDatabaseExistence(string dbName)
        {
            //get connection string
            string connectionStrAdmin = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionAdmin"].ConnectionString;

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStrAdmin))
            {
                //open
                conn.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(SCHEMA_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE @dbName", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dbName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dbName;

                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    Debug.WriteLine($"count: {count}");

                    if (count > 0)
                        return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

**Add a `JavaScript JSON Configuration File` to your project** (name: appsettings.json)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add New Item...**
- Select **JavaScript JSON Configuration File** (name: appsettings.json)
- Click **Add**

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySqlConnectionAdmin": "Server=localhost;Database=information_schema;Uid=test;Pwd=mySuperSecretPassword;"
  }
}
```

**Set File Properties**:

- In Solution Explorer, select **appsettings.json**
- In Properties Window, for **Copy to Output Directory** select **Copy Always**

**Install/Download NuGet package**: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

- In Solution Explorer, expand <project name>
- Right-click <project name> and select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse** tab
- In the search box, type: **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json**
- Scroll to the top, and select **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json**
- Select desired version (ex: 7.0.0), and click **Install**
- If prompted *Visual Studio is about to make changes to this solution. Click OK to proceed with the changes listed below...*, click **OK**

**Add a class** (name: HelperMySql.cs)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class...** (name: HelperMySql.cs)

**HelperMySql.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace DatabaseMySqlTest
{
    public class HelperMySql
    {
        public static bool CheckDatabaseExistence(string dbName)
        {
            //create new instance
            Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            string? connectionStrAdmin = configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnectionAdmin");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"connectionStrAdmin: {connectionStrAdmin}");

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStrAdmin))
            {
                //open
                conn.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(SCHEMA_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE @dbName", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dbName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dbName;

                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    Debug.WriteLine($"count: {count}");

                    if (count > 0)
                        return true;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DatabaseMySqlTest // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ToDo: change to desired database name
            string dbName = "testdb";
            Console.WriteLine($"{dbName} exists? {HelperMySql.CheckDatabaseExistence(dbName)}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [NullReferenceException trying to read connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450138/nullreferenceexception-trying-to-read-connection-string)
- [Looking inside ConfigurationManager in .NET 6](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-1-looking-inside-configurationmanager-in-dotnet-6/)
- [ConfigurationBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)
- [ConfigurationBuilder.Build Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder.build?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)
- [ConfigurationExtensions.GetConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)
- [using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)
- [$ - string interpolation (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)
- [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: Thank you for your time trying to help me. I have a few [n00b] questions: 
(1) In the configuration file I have to provide the database name, which existence I'm not sure of? This seems illogical to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
(2) Is this the safest and optimal way to check for database existence?
(3) Why `GetDatabases()` if it's not being used anywhere?
(4) I don't understand some portions of the code, so can you point me to some good book or a course on this subject, so I can learn?

Comment: Also, I've read on StackOverflow that `appsettings.json` is now preferred method instead of `app.config`?

Comment: 1) MySQL has a number of default databases which one can see if one opens `MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client`, logs in, and types: `show databases;`.  2) The "safest" thing is to not check for database existence because checking for database existence requires certain permissions. 3) `GetDatabases` was a "bonus" method. I've removed it. 4) It's unclear what _portions of the code_ you don't understand. As general guidance, use your favorite search engine to search for any terms you're unfamiliar with (ex: `c# using`).

Comment: _I've read on StackOverflow that `appsettings.json` is now preferred method instead of `app.config`_: According to [Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings): _In ASP.NET Core the configuration system is very flexible, and the connection string could be stored in appsettings.json, an environment variable, the user secret store, or another configuration source_.

Comment: _....WinForms, WPF, and ASP.NET 4 applications have a tried and tested connection string pattern. The connection string should be added to your application's App.config file (Web.config if you are using ASP.NET). If your connection string contains sensitive information, such as username and password, you can protect the contents of the configuration file using [Protected Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#encrypting-configuration-file-sections-using-protected-configuration)_

Comment: Very seldom should the `root` user be used within an application. Instead, create a user with the minimum privileges needed.

Answer (score 1):

you command is `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATAWHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'database_name';` and it clearly says that your `SCHEMATAWHERE`  should have a space between, so the correct command will be `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'database_name';`

Also, please define your connection string in the config file.

And you are checking the return value against an integer 1. so I think you are making mistake here. you need to compare it with your database name.

There is a simple command to check for the same `SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'database_name';`

Comment: I compared return value with database name, and it didn't work, i.e. `return myCommand.ExecuteScalar() == "database_name";`. What did work is `return myCommand.ExecuteScalar() != null;`.

Comment: What is the return value of `myCommand.ExecuteScalar()` if it's not a `string`?

Comment: it returns object, you need to cast it to string

Comment: I think your database name is different in case. string comparison is case-sensitive. so "x" != "X". or it's really not present in your server. so you could verify by running the command first directly in your workbench

Comment: Casting it to `string` worked, as well doing a `ToString()` on the object. Thanks!!

Comment: @Nobidag297 may I know the reason why have you unaccepted this answer?